# How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?

Tags: enums, typescript

TypeScript has a bunch of different ways to define an enum:

```
enum Alpha { X, Y, Z }
const enum Beta { X, Y, Z }
declare enum Gamma { X, Y, Z }
declare const enum Delta { X, Y, Z }
```

If I try to use a value from `Gamma` at runtime, I get an error because `Gamma` is not defined, but that's not the case for `Delta` or `Alpha`? What does `const` or `declare` mean on the declarations here?

There's also a `preserveConstEnums` compiler flag -- how does this interact with these?

Comment: [I just wrote an article about this](https://tusksoft.com/blog/posts/11/const-enums-in-typescript-1-4-and-how-they-differ-from-standard-enums), though it has more to do with comparing const to non const enums

Answer (score 291, accepted):

There are four different aspects to enums in TypeScript you need to be aware of. First, some definitions:

#### *"lookup object"*

If you write this enum:

```
enum Foo { X, Y }
```

TypeScript will emit the following object:

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    Foo[Foo["X"] = 0] = "X";
    Foo[Foo["Y"] = 1] = "Y";
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

I'll refer to this as *the lookup object*. Its purpose is twofold: to serve as a mapping from *strings* to *numbers*, e.g. when writing `Foo.X` or `Foo['X']`, and to serve as a mapping from *numbers* to *strings*. That reverse mapping is useful for debugging or logging purposes -- you will often have the value `0` or `1` and want to get the corresponding string `"X"` or `"Y"`.

#### *"declare"* or "*ambient*"

In TypeScript, you can "declare" things that the compiler should know about, but not actually emit code for. This is useful when you have libraries like jQuery that define some object (e.g. `$`) that you want type information about, but don't need any code created by the compiler. The spec and other documentation refers to declarations made this way as being in an "ambient" context; it is important to note that all declarations in a `.d.ts` file are "ambient" (either requiring an explicit `declare` modifier or having it implicitly, depending on the declaration type).

#### *"inlining"*

For performance and code size reasons, it's often preferable to have a reference to an enum member replaced by its numeric equivalent when compiled:

```
enum Foo { X = 4 }
var y = Foo.X; // emits "var y = 4";
```

The spec calls this *substitution*, I will call it *inlining* because it sounds cooler. Sometimes you will *not* want enum members to be inlined, for example because the enum value might change in a future version of the API.

---

## Enums, how do they work?

Let's break this down by each aspect of an enum. Unfortunately, each of these four sections is going to reference terms from all of the others, so you'll probably need to read this whole thing more than once.

### computed vs non-computed (constant)

Enum members can either be *computed* or not. The spec calls non-computed members *constant*, but I'll call them *non-computed* to avoid confusion with *const*.

A *computed* enum member is one whose value is not known at compile-time. References to computed members cannot be inlined, of course. Conversely, a *non-computed* enum member is once whose value *is* known at compile-time. References to non-computed members are always inlined.

Which enum members are computed and which are non-computed? First, all members of a `const` enum are constant (i.e. non-computed), as the name implies. For a non-const enum, it depends on whether you're looking at an *ambient* (declare) enum or a non-ambient enum.

A member of a `declare enum` (i.e. ambient enum) is constant *if and only if* it has an initializer. Otherwise, it is computed. Note that in a `declare enum`, only numeric initializers are allowed. Example:

```
declare enum Foo {
    X, // Computed
    Y = 2, // Non-computed
    Z, // Computed! Not 3! Careful!
    Q = 1 + 1 // Error
}
```

Finally, members of non-declare non-const enums are always considered to be computed. However, their initializing expressions are reduced down to constants if they're computable at compile-time. This means non-const enum members are never inlined (this behavior changed in TypeScript 1.5, see "Changes in TypeScript" at the bottom)

### const vs non-const

#### const

An enum declaration can have the `const` modifier. If an enum is `const`, *all* references to its members inlined.

```
const enum Foo { A = 4 }
var x = Foo.A; // emitted as "var x = 4;", always
```

const enums do not produce a lookup object when compiled. For this reason, it is an error to reference `Foo` in the above code except as part of a member reference. No `Foo` object will be present at runtime.

#### non-const

If an enum declaration does not have the `const` modifier, references to its members are inlined only if the member is non-computed. A non-const, non-declare enum will produce a lookup object.

### declare (ambient) vs non-declare

An important preface is that `declare` in TypeScript has a very specific meaning: *This object exists somewhere else*. It's for describing *existing* objects. Using `declare` to define objects that don't actually exist can have bad consequences; we'll explore those later.

#### declare

A `declare enum` will not emit a lookup object. References to its members are inlined if those members are computed (see above on computed vs non-computed).

It's important to note that other forms of reference to a `declare enum` *are* allowed, e.g. this code is *not* a compile error but *will* fail at runtime:

```
// Note: Assume no other file has actually created a Foo var at runtime
declare enum Foo { Bar } 
var s = 'Bar';
var b = Foo[s]; // Fails
```

This error falls under the category of "Don't lie to the compiler". If you don't have an object named `Foo` at runtime, don't write `declare enum Foo`!

A `declare const enum` is not different from a `const enum`, except in the case of --preserveConstEnums (see below).

#### non-declare

A non-declare enum produces a lookup object if it is not `const`. Inlining is described above.

### --preserveConstEnums flag

This flag has exactly one effect: non-declare const enums will emit a lookup object. Inlining is not affected. This is useful for debugging.

---

## Common Errors

The most common mistake is to use a `declare enum` when a regular `enum` or `const enum` would be more appropriate. A common form is this:

```
module MyModule {
    // Claiming this enum exists with 'declare', but it doesn't...
    export declare enum Lies {
        Foo = 0,
        Bar = 1     
    }
    var x = Lies.Foo; // Depend on inlining
}

module SomeOtherCode {
    // x ends up as 'undefined' at runtime
    import x = MyModule.Lies;

    // Try to use lookup object, which ought to exist
    // runtime error, canot read property 0 of undefined
    console.log(x[x.Foo]);
}
```

Remember the golden rule: *Never `declare` things that don't actually exist*. Use `const enum` if you always want inlining, or `enum` if you want the lookup object.

---

## Changes in TypeScript

Between TypeScript 1.4 and 1.5, there was a change in the behavior (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2183) to make all members of non-declare non-const enums be treated as computed, even if they're explicitly initialized with a literal. This "unsplit the baby", so to speak, making the inlining behavior more predictable and more cleanly separating the concept of `const enum` from regular `enum`. Prior to this change, non-computed members of non-const enums were inlined more aggressively.

Comment: A really awesome answer. It cleared up so many things for me, not just enums.

Comment: I wish I could vote you up more than once ... didn't know about that breaking change. In proper semantic versioning this could be considered a bump to the major version :-/

Comment: A very helpful comparison of the various `enum` types, thank you!

Comment: @Ryan this is very helpful, thanks! Now we just need [Web Essentials 2015](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/67) to produce the proper `const` for declared enum types.

Comment: This answer seems to go into great detail explaining a situation in 1.4, and then at the very end it says “but 1.5 changed all that and now it’s much simpler.” Assuming I understand things correctly, this organization is going to get more and more inappropriate as this answer gets older: I strongly recommend putting the simpler, current situation *first*, and only *after that* saying “but if you’re using 1.4 or earlier, things are a little more complicated.”

Comment: In your "computed vs non-computed (constant)" example where you have "declare enum Foo { ... " that comment about an Error is not true. That snippet compiles just fine.

Answer (score 41):

There are a few things going on here.  Let's go case by case.

## enum

```
enum Cheese { Brie, Cheddar }
```

First, a plain old enum.  When compiled to JavaScript, this will emit a lookup table.

The lookup table looks like this:

```
var Cheese;
(function (Cheese) {
    Cheese[Cheese["Brie"] = 0] = "Brie";
    Cheese[Cheese["Cheddar"] = 1] = "Cheddar";
})(Cheese || (Cheese = {}));
```

Then when you have `Cheese.Brie` in TypeScript, it emits `Cheese.Brie` in JavaScript which evaluates to 0. `Cheese[0]` emits `Cheese[0]` and actually evaluates to `"Brie"`.

## const enum

```
const enum Bread { Rye, Wheat }
```

No code is actually emitted for this! Its values are inlined. The following emit the value 0 itself in JavaScript:

```
Bread.Rye
Bread['Rye']
```

`const enum`s' inlining might be useful for performance reasons.

But what about `Bread[0]`?  This will error out at runtime and your compiler should catch it.  There's no lookup table and the compiler doesn't inline here.

Note that in the above case, the --preserveConstEnums flag will cause Bread to emit a lookup table. Its values will still be inlined though.

## declare enum

As with other uses of `declare`, `declare` emits no code and expects you to have defined the actual code elsewhere.  This emits no lookup table:

```
declare enum Wine { Red, Wine }
```

`Wine.Red` emits `Wine.Red` in JavaScript, but there won't be any Wine lookup table to reference so it's an error unless you've defined it elsewhere.

## declare const enum

This emits no lookup table:

```
declare const enum Fruit { Apple, Pear }
```

But it does inline! `Fruit.Apple` emits 0.  But again `Fruit[0]` will error out at runtime because it's not inlined and there's no lookup table.

I've written this up in [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Emits%20a%20lookup%20table%0D%0Aenum%20Cheese%20%7B%20Brie%2C%20Cheddar%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Emits%20Cheese.Brie%2C%20which%20evaluates%20to%200%0D%0ACheese.Brie%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Emits%20Cheese%5B0%5D%2C%20which%20evaluates%20to%20%22Brie%22%0D%0ACheese%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20code%20is%20actually%20emitted%20for%20this!%20Its%20values%20are%0D%0A%2F%2F%20inlined%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20enum%20Bread%20%7B%20Rye%2C%20Wheat%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20These%20emits%20the%20value%200%20itself.%20%20This%20might%20be%20useful%20for%0D%0A%2F%2F%20performance%20reasons.%0D%0ABread.Rye%0D%0ABread%5B%27Rye%27%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Note%20that%20in%20the%20above%20case%2C%20the%20--preserveConstEnums%20flag%20will%0D%0A%2F%2F%20cause%20Bread%20to%20emit%20a%20lookup%20table.%20%20Its%20values%20will%20still%20be%20inlined%0D%0A%2F%2F%20though.%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20a%20compiler%20error.%20%20There%27s%20no%20lookup%20table.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20the%20compiler%20doesn%27t%20inline%20%27Rye%27%20here.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20That%20means%20you%20can%20be%20guarenteed%20that%20even%20if%20you%20change%20it%0D%0A%2F%2F%20to%20be%20%27rye%27%20(lowercase)%20and%20any%20code%20will%0D%0A%2F%2F%20still%20work%0D%0A%0D%0ABread%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20emits%20no%20lookup%20table%0D%0Adeclare%20enum%20Wine%20%7B%20Red%2C%20Wine%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20emits%20Wine.Red.%20%20There%20won%27t%20be%20any%20Wine%0D%0A%2F%2F%20to%20reference%20so%20it%27s%20an%20error%20unless%20you%27ve%20defined%0D%0A%2F%2F%20it%20elsewhere%0D%0AWine.Red%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20emits%20no%20lookup%20table%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20enum%20Fruit%20%7B%20Apple%2C%20Pear%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20it%20does%20inline!%20This%20emits%200%0D%0AFruit.Apple%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%20again%20this%20one%20will%20error%20out%0D%0AFruit%5B0%5D) playground.  I recommend playing there to understand which TypeScript emits which JavaScript.

Comment: I recommend updating this answer: As of Typescript 3.3.3, `Bread[0]` throws a compiler error: **“A const enum member can only be accessed using a string literal.”**

Comment: Hm... is that different from what the answer says? "But what about Bread[0]? This will error out at runtime and your compiler should catch it. There's no lookup table and the compiler doesn't inline here."