# Why doesn't TS use Symbols for enums

Tags: typescript, enums

ES6 symbols is a great fit for enums as they avoid collision. I thouhgt that TS `enum` type used Symbols for enums if `target:'es6'`, but it doesn't:

```
enum Role {Employee, Manager, Admin}
let role: Role = Role.Employee;
```

transpiles to

```
var Role;
(function (Role) {
    Role[Role["Employee"] = 0] = "Employee";
    Role[Role["Manager"] = 1] = "Manager";
    Role[Role["Admin"] = 2] = "Admin";
})(Role || (Role = {}));
let role = Role.Employee;
```

any ideas why? With such approach `Role.Employee` has the value of `0`, and any other enum with the value of `0` can be used instead of `Role.Employee` in runtime?

Comment: Take a look at this issue: [Allow enums of types other than number](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206)

Comment: @NitzanTomer, thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 31):

ES `Symbol` is about uniqueness whereas TypeScript `enum` is about named constants. Being **unique** and being **constant** are two different things.

We can serialize `enum` structure as it is essentially just an object. But `Symbol` is a different story. You cannot serialize it.

So, when we say constant, we actually mean to use that value as it is which exactly what `enum` provides. But `Symbol` is not a value that you want to use. It is more like an identity that we wish to make that nobody should be able to clone/replicate.

A constant is something that stays constant. So some code that can run in two different environments, like Node.js and Browser, both will understand the constant value to be same (in simple words, the developer is creating a value for constant, ex. string or number). But for `Symbol`, imagine it to not have any notion of value. If we attempt to use it as value, then it means it is two separate things (because the runtime is creating those `Symbol` values, not developer).

In the same light, if you have used redux, we prefer `string` over `Symbol` to represent our action.

Further, [in case of TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript), `enum` can also be used as `ambient` or `substitution` value. In this case, it is the only compiler for whom the enum value matters. During compilation, `type erasure` may remove `enum` reference altogether. Now, this is something you cannot do with Symbol. Creation of `Symbol` is runtime only activity. So if we use `Symbol` for `enum`, then we lose to the ability of `enum` to be **compile-time only** feature.

Thus not using `Symbol` for `enum` seems a sensible choice.