# Redux Actions: TypeScript enum member uniqueness?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I am in the process of converting an app from JavaScript ES6 to TypeScript, and will probably have mixed JavaScript / TypeScript for a long time.

I have successfully set up a TypeScript Redux (4.0.0-beta.2) store and defined some TypeScript Redux Actions using enums as such:

```
export enum SignInActionType {
    SignedIn = "SIGNED_IN",
    SignedOut = "SIGNED_OUT",
}

export interface SignInAction extends Action<SignInActionType> {
}
```

The reducer then switches on those values

```
export const signInReducer: Reducer<SignInState, SignInAction> = (state: SignInState = initialState, action: SignInAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SignInActionType.SignedIn:
            return {...state, state: SignInType.SignedIn};
        case SignInActionType.SignedOut:
            return {...state, state: SignInType.SignedOut};
    }
    return state;
};
```

After attaching the Chrome debugger and stepping into the reducer function i can see that `action.type` in the switch statement is the string of the enum member e.g. `SIGNED_IN`.

TypeScript doesn't seem to detect overlaps in enum member names.

e.g.

```
export enum ThisIsAMistake {
    SignMyGuestBook = "SIGNED_IN",
}
```

The problem I would face would be that the reducer might run even though the message was not targeted at that reducer.

The "promise" of enums in some other languages (e.g. Java, or more similar to TypeScript - Swift) is that even though two enum members share a name, they are not the same.

If I understand correctly, this basically means that I get a tiny bit more compile time help with not misspelling something, but I would still need to make sure that the strings are unique?

TL;DR

- Does TypeScript offer a way to express enum string uniqueness?
- Does there exist a standard approach for this in the TypeScript world?

Comment: In js there are `Symbols`, however they are not allowed as enum values yet.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825162/why-doesnt-ts-use-symbols-for-enums

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the naming convention which Redux uses actions(i.e. `const ACTION_NAME='ACTION_NAME'` inside enums.

```
enum ActionTypes {
    FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USER'
}
```

The main idea here is that on the left and right side we always have the same name(i.e. FETCH_USERS)

If you try to do the below - you will get an error saying "Duplicate identifier 'FETCH_USERS'"

```
enum ActionTypes {
    FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USER'
    FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_SOMETHING_ELSE'
}
```

Hope it helps :)