# Using Symbol as enum

Tags: typescript

Enums are typescript feature.

You can create enums this way:

```
enum Constants {
  label: "label"
}
export default Constants
```

I want to set the value of the enum to be a symbol, is it possible?

```
enum Constants {
  label: Symbol()
}
export default Constants
```

But typescript doesn't accept it. and it says:

> Only numeric enums can have computed members, but this expression has
> type 'symbol'. If you do not need exhaustiveness checks, consider
> using an object literal instead.ts(18033)

Can we use symbols as enums in typescript?

Comment: "*Can we use symbols as enums in typescript?*" is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @VLAZ, no it isn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't TS use Symbols for enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825162/why-doesnt-ts-use-symbols-for-enums)

Comment: @colinD, Hi. No, I want to use the symbol in my code, I have a function which accepts a list of parameters as an array. Inside this function, I do check to see if this symbol exists, so _I can do something with it_, I can for sure define the symbol in a separate file. But I think using enums in this particular scenario is a good idea. Because I have different set of symbols.

Answer (score 1):

No, enums can have a very limited amount of values. They could be strings or numbers or a computed expression which evaluates to a constant. Here is the list of computed expressions from [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members)

> The enum member is initialized with a constant enum expression. A constant enum expression is a subset of TypeScript expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile time. An expression is a constant enum expression if it is:
>
> 1. a literal enum expression (basically a string literal or a numeric literal)
> 2. a reference to previously defined constant enum member (which can originate from a different enum)
> 3. a parenthesized constant enum expression
> 4. one of the `+`, `-`, `~` unary operators applied to constant enum expression
> 5. `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<<`, `>>`, `>>>`, `&`, `|`, `^` binary operators with constant enum expressions as operands
>
> It is a compile time error for constant enum expressions to be evaluated to `NaN` or `Infinity`.