# typescript enum is not translated correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but the emitted javascript is choking.

In my interfaces.d.ts file, I have:

```
declare enum SideEnum {
    None = 0, Buy, Sell, SellShort
}

interface Order {
    symbol: string,
    price: number,
    qty: number,
    side: SideEnum
}
```

In my code, I have a function that does:

```
textToSide(text :string) : SideEnum {
    if (text === 'buy')
        return SideEnum.Buy;
    else if (text === 'sell')
        return SideEnum.Sell;
    else if (text === 'sellshort')
        return SideEnum.SellShort;
    else 
        return SideEnum.None;
}
```

And finally, when I am using the above, I do:

```
onFormSubmit = (evt:any) => {
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    const order :Order = {
        symbol: fields.symbol,
        price: parseFloat(fields.price),
        qty: parseInt(fields.qty),
        side: this.textToSide(fields.side)
    }
    const orders :Order[] = [...this.state.orders, order];

    evt.preventDefault();

    /* more stuff here */
}
```

When I run the code, I get: "ReferenceError: SideEnum is not defined". My app.bundle.js is showing that the confusion is here:

```
{
        key: 'textToSide',
        value: function textToSide(text) {
            if (text === 'buy') return SideEnum.Buy;else if (text === 'sell') return SideEnum.Sell;else if (text === 'sellshort') return SideEnum.SellShort;else return SideEnum.None;
        }
    },
```

What am i doing wrong?  Any possibility that I should be using the fat arrow when invoking this.textToSide()?

thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript section "Common Errors"

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion in the comment by Ryan, I did (instead of plain 'declare'):

declare const enum SideEnum {
.....
}

and everything fell into place.

Thank you