# Typescript Enum Object.values() return value

Tags: typescript, enums

Why does `Object.values()` and `Object.keys()` always give both the keys and the values?

Consider the following code:

```js
enum Enum {
    FOO,
    BAR
}

console.log(Object.values(Enum));
console.log(Object.keys(Enum));
```

The output of this would be:

```js
[ 'FOO', 'BAR', 0, 1 ]
[ '0', '1', 'FOO', 'BAR' ]
```

Why does it do that and how do I only get the keys and values?

Comment: More info on enums: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript. How to get keys/values: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17198#issuecomment-315400819

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(Enum).filter(([key]) => isNaN(parseInt(key))))` to get clean object

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's how `enum` types are transpiled by TypeScript.

```
enum Enum {
    FOO,
    BAR
}
```

will become

```
"use strict";
var Enum;
(function (Enum) {
    Enum[Enum["FOO"] = 0] = "FOO";
    Enum[Enum["BAR"] = 1] = "BAR";
})(Enum || (Enum = {}));
```

Notice that both numeric keys and string keys are provided for easy mapping to and from both types, enabling you to do something like this:

```
const value = Enum.FOO;  // inferred type Enum.FOO
const key = Enum[value]; // inferred type string
```

If you want to get an array of only the numeric or string keys, you can do this:

```
const numericKeys = Object.keys(Enum).map(x => parseInt(x)).filter(x => !isNaN(x));
const stringKeys = Object.keys(Enum).filter(x => isNaN(parseInt(x)));
```

Or for the numeric or string values (requires the `es2017` library in your `tsconfig`):

```
const numericValues = Object.values(Enum).filter(x => typeof x === "number");
const stringValues = Object.values(Enum).filter(x => typeof x === "string");
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Is there a way to only get the values then? I suppose it would be possible to get that result by using Array.splice() but I am not sure if the order is always the same (although it seems that way).

Comment: `const values = Object.values(Enum).filter(v => typeof v === 'number');`

Answer (score 2):

The following solution should always work, no matter what types are the keys or values:

```
// sample enum:
enum someEnum {
   CREATE = 0,
   DELETE = 1,
   UPDATE = 2,
}

const firstHalf = Object.keys(someEnum).reduce((acc:any[], curr, index, arr) => {
      if (index < arr.length / 2) acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, []);

const secondHalf = Object.keys(someEnum).reduce((acc:any[], curr, index, arr) => {
      if (index >= arr.length / 2) acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(`first half: ${firstHalf}`); // 0,1,2
console.log(`second half: ${secondHalf}`); // CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE
```

Answer (score 2):

Values will not be duplicated if you set them as `KEY = value` instead:

```
enum MyEnum = {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}

Object.keys(MyEnum) -> ['FOO', 'BAR']
Object.values(MyEnum) -> ['foo', 'bar']
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAYgeR1AXigHIAzAe3OIBoMoAhAQQCVCSAjAQwCdi0BfNGgDG5EAGdyAG2AA6KeQDmAChzsAVsGEAXWQGtgcccvhJIASnMixkmfKWqNW3QDdOUsMGOnkloA)

Depending on your situation, updating your enums to this format could be simpler than adding helper functions to filter out the dupes.

Comment: This is not true when the enum values are of type number instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple utils to isolate for the values and keys you'd expect as defined in your enum:

```
const enumValues = (e: Object) =>
  Object.values(e).filter((v) => typeof e[v] !== 'number');

const enumKeys = (e: Object) =>
  Object.keys(e).filter(isNaN as any);
```