# How can I get the a json object of typescript object from monaco editor?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, monaco-editor

**Problem:**
I need to convert typescript model which is using intellisense from extraLibs(option in monaco editor) from monaco editor into a json object so I can send that to API for processsing.

**Here is the code you can copy and paste this into Monaco Editor Playground for further testing**

```js
// extra libraries
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib('enum Types {type1 = 1,type2 = 2} interface Page {name: string;type: Types;}', 'ts:filename/facts.d.ts');

var jsCode = `
// This is typescript model which user can edit in the monaco editor
var model: Page = {
    name: "Page",
    type: Types.type1
}


// I need above typescript model in JSON form to send it to API like below
/*
{
    "name": "Page",
    "type": 1
}
 */
`;

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: jsCode,
    language: "typescript"
});

// I was trying something
monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker().then(x => {
    x('').then(y => {
        y.getEmitOutput('hello').then(z => {
            console.log(z)
        });
    })
})
```

> **Note: I am working in Angular**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getValue()](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#getvalue) to get last text in editor. Then you have to use [typescript compiler services api](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to transpile that to javascript code

**Example**

```js
const jsCode = `var model: Page = {
    name: "Page",
    type: Types.type1
}
`

const container = document.getElementById('container');

require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs' }});
window.MonacoEnvironment = { getWorkerUrl: () => proxy };

let proxy = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
 self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/'
 };
 importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
`], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], async function () {

const libCode = `enum Types {
type1 = 1,
type2 = 2
}

interface Page {
name: string;
type: Types;
}`

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(libCode, 'ts:filename/facts.d.ts');

 let editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
  value: jsCode,
  language: 'typescript',
  theme: 'vs-dark' 
 });
   
  const result = window.ts.transpileModule(libCode + editor.getValue(), { compilerOptions: { module: window.ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }});
  console.log(result);

  
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.20.0/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/3.9.3/typescript.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Output is not as i needed. Json should be like i had in the question. Value of Types.type1 which is 1

Comment: Well then you have to implement your own typescript-ish transpiler which evaluates [enums to literal values as currently it is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript).

Comment: Actually we can use JSON.stringify(typscriptObject) to get a JSON but I am not sure how can  we run that function and get the output as needed.