# How to distinguish a string value from a string enum, without an extra lookup?

Tags: typescript

In an interface definition I use a src member for an icon which can either be a string (for an image path) or a predefined icon (a name of that):

```
interface IIconProperties {
    src?: string | Codicon;
}

export enum Codicon {
    add = "add",
}
```

Now on render I have to generate different output depending on the value. But since both are actually strings I cannot tell them apart:

```
if (typeof src === "string") {
    // Always taken.
} else {
    // Never hit.
}
```

So I tried to identify the enum somehow (`src instanceof enum`, `typeof src === "enum"`), which is not valid syntax. What can I do to differentiate between the two types, without having to use a separate lookup map (when I would use numbers instead of strings in the enum)?

Comment: The type system only exists at compile time. At runtime (when `typeof src === "string" runs) then none of the types exist. You can see that in the compiled code `src` will have [its type erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) and it's a plain JavaScript variable. It will not be aware of TypeScript constructs. Also of possible interest: [How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818849)

Comment: However, you can still check for other types like instances of classes. So, it's not entirely true there wouldn't be anything like that at runtime. But thanks for the links.

Comment: *classes* are different, since they are not purely a type system construct - they exist at runtime. After all, you can call `new MyClass()` which is processed at runtime. Moreover, you'd be using the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check for classes which is part of JavaScript and will check if a given value is an instance of a given object. All of these things are already present at runtime, so type erasure does not affect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is: You can't. `enum` is not a Javascript type so, you can never know by the time it's compiled.