# Typescript enums as interfaces

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, protobuf.js

I am using a library for TS generation (ts-protoc-gen), which generates the following for enums:

```
export interface AnimalTypeMap {
    Dog: 0;
    Cat: 1;
    Fish: 2;
    Bird: 3;
}

export const AnimalType: AnimalTypeMap;
```

1. How should I consume it?

```
if (arg === AnimalType.Bird) {} // **ERROR**: Variable 'AnimalType' is used before being assigned
if (arg === AnimalTypeMap.Bird) {} // **ERROR**:'AnimalTypeMap' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

2. How can it export a const without initializing it?

Comment: Why do you not use normal enums? Interfaces *do not exist at runtime*, so you cannot do what you're trying here.

Comment: Other option would be exporting this as value: `export const AnimalType = { Dog: 0, Cat: 1 } as const`

Comment: Relevant: [How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818849)

Answer (score 0):

change your enum class in typescript like bellow

```
 export interface AnimalTypeMap 
     {
    Dog: Dog;
    Cat: Cat;
    Fish: Fish;
    Bird: Bird;
     }
```

and in backend use

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum AnimalTypeMap {
{
        Dog: 1;
        Cat: 2;
        Fish: 3;
        Bird: 4;
         }
```

if you use c#

Comment: the interface is auto generated, I can't control it

Comment: if you use code generator same swagger or other, Just enough add [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] on your enum

Comment: This is not possible, the types are defined in protobuff files.
Please assume my first code snippet is given and cannot be modified, how would you consume it in pure TS?

Comment: Use this :  if (arg === AnimalType['Bird']) {}

Answer (score 0):

If you include both --ts-out and --js-out to protoc then this works for me:

```
import {AnimalType, AnimalTypeMap} from "./generated/AnimalType_pb"
const animalType:AnimalTypeMap[keyof AnimalTypeMap] = AnimalType.Bird;
```

But it's not exactly intuitive and I don't think it's the right way to do it. But at least it works.

EDIT: There's a fork: https://github.com/gnomesley/ts-protoc-gen that generates normal TypeScript enums. It's much more intuitive.