# Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)) in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript I'd like to get all values of an `enum` type in an array. The equivalent in C# has been this:

```cs
public static TEnum[] GetValues<TEnum>() where TEnum : Enum
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
        .OfType<TEnum>()
        .ToArray();
}
```

What's the best translation for this method into Typescript so that a possible usage would be:

```
const allCountries: Country[] = GetEnumValues<Country>();
```

Update: I'm using Typescript 3.9.4 and it's no problem to use a newer version.

Comment: What does this code do, exactly? Get all values from an enum? Get all keys from an enum?

Comment: Also, it's likely not possible. [TypeScript enums might not exist at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript) depends on which version of them you use. There is an additional problem that the ones that *do* exist at runtime will be compiled as objects where the keys and values are double bound in both directions, e.g., `enum E { "A", "B", "C" }` emits `E = { 0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", A: 0, B: 1, C: 2 }` as code.

Comment: Transliterating is almost never a good idea. You end up with a lot of XY problems that way. Show how you plan to use it in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In can be easily done. You just can't use it with `const enum`. Typescript will complain if you use that, because its not available at runtime.

```
function getEnumValues<T>(en: any): T[] { // maybe it can be done without using any but i don't know
   return Object.keys(en)
     .filter(k => !isFinite(Number(k))) // this filters the reverse mappings: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings
     .map(k => en[k]);
}
```

See also as example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-z2swch

Comment: The usage would be `const allCountries = getEnumValues<Country>(Country);`, wouldn't it? Looks strange but it works. Furthermore: I never asked for `const enum`! Don't know why you mention it?

Comment: Why not this signature: `getEnumValues<T>(en: T): T[]`?

Comment: @Marcel `T` describes an enum value, not the whole enum. In your examle: `Country.UK` would have the type `Country` so `const v: Country = Country.UK` works but `Country` itself is not of type `Country` so `const v: Country = Country` wont work.