# Typescript exported enum is undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm writing some typescript type definitions for an existing react native module.

What I've done so far:

1. added path to my `index.d.ts` file in the react native module's `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "react-native-my-module",
// ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "typings/index.d.ts"
}
```

2. write my type definitions as follow:

```
import { EventSubscriptionVendor } from 'react-native';

declare module "react-native-my-module" {

    export enum MyValues {
        ValueOne = 'one',
        ValueTwo = 'two'
    }

    export interface SomeType<T> {
        code: number,
        description: string,
        message: T
    }


    // ...
}
```

The  problem I have is that when I use this react native module in a react native test project, the type definitions seem to be used in my IDE but at runtime, the code below gives me `undefined` for the enum:

```
import Blabla, { MyValues, SomeType } from "react-native-my-module";

// ...

console.log('MyValues is =', MyValues); // gives  'MyValues is =, undefined'
```

Questions:

- why is my enum undefined in the test project?
- is there any other conf to add to the react-native  module or the test project for typescript to work correctly?

Comment: You have [an ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) thanks to `declare`. Anything in the ambient context is removed at runtime. [Same thing happens to ambient enums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28818850/). In general, don't use `declare` if you want to use something at runtime.

Comment: @VLAZ I've just tried to move up the `export enum ...` (before the declare module...) and it is still undefined...

Comment: I've also tried to remove the "declare"  before "module" and I'm still having the same problem...

Comment: I'm wondering if when using `"types"` field of `package.json`, we can only have type declarations in those ts files and thus no value readable at runtime... See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package