# Will the order be respected if I use Object.values on a TypeScript enum?

Tags: typescript

I need to create an array from all of the values in an emum. This seems to work:

```
enum Foo {
  one = 'one',
  two = 'two',
  three = 'three',
}

console.log(Object.values(Foo));
```

However will the order always be `one`, `two`, `three`? It seems to be this way when I test but as `Foo` is an object in JavaScript I don't know if this can be relied upon?

Comment: Also relevant: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219) and [How do the different enum variants work in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818849)

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why order matters here.