# Difference between using `typeof` a constant and `enum` in Tyepscript

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between using `typeof` a constant and `enum`?

Example:

```js
const TYPE_A = 'a'
const TYPE_B = 'b'
type MyType =
  | typeof TYPE_A
  | typeof TYPE_B

type Resut = {
  name: string
  type: MyType
}

// and 

enum QuestionType {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
}

type Resut = {
  name: string
  type: MyType
}
```

My goal is to use the `"a"` and `"b"` values also in other parts of the code. This is why I proposed the `typeof variable` but I dont' know if is the better solution.

I saw there is also `const enum` but I didn't understand the difference

Comment: One difference: changing `TYPE_A = 'a'` to `TYPE_A = 'aa'` will affect the derived type.

Comment: @VLAZ What do you mean? Why should i change the value of the constant?

Comment: Well, why would you use variables instead of `type MyType = "a" | "b"`? Since you want to derive the type, seems like you want to change them. If you don't, then I'm not sure what the first construct is showing off.

Comment: @VLAZ I use variables instead of `type MyType = "a" | "b" ` because I can use these constants also in other parts of the code..

Comment: Right - context missing from your question.

Comment: @VLAX, thank you, you're right. I updated my main message

Comment: Why not use a string literal type? `type MyType = 'a' | 'b'`

Answer (score 0):

One important distinction between `typeof` and `enum` is what happens during compilation and the availability during runtime.

Type information is removed by the compiler whereas standard enums are represented at [runtime by an object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), or as VLAZ has pointed out, are inlined by the compiler when using const enums.

Comment: "*enums (in either form) are not removed from the compiled code.*" [depends on the type of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818849/how-do-the-different-enum-variants-work-in-typescript) for example a `const enum` will be inlined then removed as part of compilation [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgRUXaBLcAVATwAc4YBvAWACgYYBBGAXhgCIBDFgGmtoCEnWAIy7UAvtVCRYADwEYsUXGEIkAdHQDc1IA)

Comment: Good point, I should have clarified that further